# Android Hotspot doesn't work on Macbook pro

Tags: wifi, catalina, tethering

I'm completely new to the Mac world. I am trying to connect my Macbook Pro (13" 2020
with Catalina 10.15.6) to my Android Hotspot. This seems to work because my macbook can connect to the hotspot and it responds to the ping. But whenever I try to open a web page the result is the same as not connected. Is anyone else experiencing this problem?

Comment: I know my son is doing it with a macbook pro 2015 running yosemite and an android with 4g. The macbook was on my wifi first so we knew all was fine then disconnected and connected by the android 4g. Works to get him into his bank.

Answer (score 2):

Before I got a new iPhone, I experienced this with my Android sometimes. It may or may not work for you, but try a physical connection. I have found that this helped me.